# Is there a way to use multiple feeds with Adafruit MQTT python client subscriptions?

Tags: python, mqtt, feed, adafruit

I'm using Adafruit IO MQTT python client to execute code based upon feeds. I want one feed to execute one function and a different to execute another. I've looked at  [this](https://github.com/adafruit/io-client-python/blob/master/examples/mqtt_subscribe.py)  and searched around but nothing I have found shows how to subscribe to multiple feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `subscribe` multiple times, as in:

```
for feed_id in ['feed1', 'feed2']:
  client.subscribe(feed_id)
```

This is a basic feature of the MQTT protocol.  Your `on_message_` handler will receive the feed id as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for that. I still don't quite understand how I specify which function is run for a given feed

Comment: You use the feed id parameter in your `on_message_` handler to determine what function to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build that yourself

Just add an if statement to the `on_message` callback to pick a different function based on the topic (feed_id) e.g.

```
def message(client, feed_id, payload, retain):
    if feed_id == 'foo/bar':
       #call foo function
       foo(paylaod)
    elif feed_id == 'bar/foo':
       #call bar function
       bar(payload)
```

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!